# How I can insert a <br> tag every 115 characters

Tags: php, regex, strlen

How can I insert a `<br>` tag every 115 characters?  Which solution is better: strlen or regex?

How I can accomplish this?

Better to understand, how was made the comment section in stage6.

http://web.archive.org/web/20071120055812/http://stage6.divx.com/user/DorkmanScott

I need exactly the formatted comments.

Comment: This sounds like an approach that is fraught with difficulties.  What's the motivation for doing this?  There may be something simpler that will work better.

Comment: im currently rebuild stage6 and need them for the comments section
like this http://web.archive.org/web/20071120055812/http://stage6.divx.com/user/DorkmanScott

Answer (score 6):

This can't really be done.  Because if you just naively insert a `<br>` tag every 115 characters in the HTML document, you might end up within another tag, which would obviously not be what you wanted.  You could use an HTML parser to parse the document, and only insert the `<br>` tag in places where text exists, but, I think that might be a little problematic, as you would have to account for inline elements, where you would want to put a `<br>` tag.

I'm guessing your problem has something to do with controlling the width of your web page, and you would probably be better off using CSS to control the width of the document.

Comment: Plus, even if you restricted the line breaking within certain tags, you'd still end up breaking in the middle of words.  CSS is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

Although the comments suggest that this is not the correct approach to use (i.e. you shouldn't need to be inserting `<br />` elements if the bounding element is set to wrap correctly), if you absolutely need to achieve something in PHP then [wordrap()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) is probably the safest function for you:

```
$wrappedString = wordwrap($string, 115, '<br />');
```

This should only be used if you're dealing with text, not with raw HTML, otherwise you might run into DOM issues. Tread carefully.

**EDIT**: if your intention is to break long words to avoid them overflowing your bounding box, you could consider adding soft hyphen (`&shy;`) entities in the longer words.

Comment: +1 for answering the question (granted it is a probably-misguided question)